# Creating Individual Reports in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am new to Microsoft Access and I am trying to create a report form where I can create a report for individual employees. I already created a form where I can enter the data for reports. My problem is, in my form I can only enter all the data of all employees. What I want is that I can select which employee I want to create a report. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first make a "Employee selection form".  This form will have a listbox of all employees and a "Create Report" button.  After the user picks an employee, they press the button which creates the report using the employee as a filter.

The button will be the hard part since there will be VBA code behind it, but Access's button making wizard will help you out (I think).